# MVC .NET Unit Test: how to test arguments are sent to view from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, mstest, controllers

I am new to MVC .NET (I have previously worked on Ruby On Rails).

I was wondering how I could write a unit test that would check that the correct arguments are passed into the view.

```
public ActionResult Users()
{
  var users = userManager.GetUsers();
  return View(users);
}
```

How do I test that the View has been passed with the list of users? Do I simply mock the View static method or is there a better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: because that would test the GetUsers method, but does not test the Users() controller method. In this test, I do not really care if GetUsers really does return me the correct result, I simply want to test whether the value received has been passed to the view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should mock the `userManager.GetUsers` method and then assert that the controller action returned a ViewResult with model that equals to the mocked list of users. Of course in order to be able to mock the `userManager.GetUsers` method this method needs to be virtual:

For example:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    private readonly IUsersManager _usersManager;
    public HomeController(IUsersManager usersManager)
    {
        _usersManager = usersManager;
    }

    public ActionResult Users()
    {
        var users = _usersManager.GetUsers();
        return View(users);
    }    
}
```

Now in your unit test you could provide a mock instance of the `IUsersManager` interface and define expectations for the `GetUsers` method.

Using a mocking framework such as [Rhino Mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks) this is a trivial task:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Users_Action_Should_Query_The_UserManager_Repository_And_Pass_The_Result_To_The_View()
{
    // arrange
    var expectedUsers = new User[] { new User() };
    var usersManagerStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IUsersManager>();
    usersManagerStub.Stub(x => x.GetUsers()).Return(expectedUsers);
    var sut = new HomeController(usersManagerStub);

    // act
    var actual = sut.Users();

    // assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(ViewResult));
    var viewResult = actual as ViewResult;
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedUsers, viewResult.Model);
}
```

and using [MVCContrib.TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) it provides you more fluent syntax simplifies the mocking of standard HTTP artifacts such as the context, session, cookies, ...:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Users_Action_Should_Query_The_UserManager_Repository_And_Pass_The_Result_To_The_View()
{
    // arrange
    var expectedUsers = new User[] { new User() };
    var usersManagerStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IUsersManager>();
    usersManagerStub.Stub(x => x.GetUsers()).Return(expectedUsers);
    var sut = new HomeController(usersManagerStub);

    // act
    var actual = sut.Users();

    // assert
    actual
        .AssertViewRendered()
        .WithViewData<User[]>()
        .ShouldEqual(expectedUsers, "");
}
```

Comment: I added the nugget package MvcContrib.TestHelper, but the extension seems like its not found - after trying out AssertViewRendered, I get 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult' does not contain a definition for 'AssertViewRendered' and no extension method 'AssertViewRendered' accepting a first ... any idea what I may be missing?

Comment: Add `using MvcContrib.TestHelper` to your `using` directives.

Comment: ha, that was simpler than I thought. Thanks @Darin!